# Solaris - all drives connected to LSI HBA's has same device id

Tags: solaris, lsi

I have deployed several Solaris/ZFS based storage servers but this particular one "Alacritech AIC ANX-1500" is behaving weird.

The server has 24 2.5" bays all populated with SSDS. The backplane is connected to 3 x LSI 9211-8i HBA with IT firmware. The OS is only detecting 3 drives while the cards bios shows all 24 drives connected. On further checking i found that all 24 drives are being detected but 22 of them are being recognized as same device id and same serial number.

Images of same :

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the controller 1 is only showing 2 drives while controller 2 is having 22. There is no information being displayed for controller 0. The controller has only 8 ports and all drives are connected as 3 controllers x 8 drives = 24.

I am not sure what is causing the issue with Solaris since there is no issue with any other OS like Linux, FreeBSD or Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps. I have tried OmniOs, OpenIndiana and NexentaStor all of them has same drives identification.